# How to draw a triangle node (gain) in a block diagram in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, nodes

I know how to make a block diagram in TikZ. With `\node[block] ...`, one can make rectangular blocks:

```
block/.style = {draw, fill=blue!20, rectangle,
                     minimum height=3em, minimum width=6em}
```

I would like to include triangular blocks in a block diagram. These represent a gain, i.e. a multiplication by a constant. So far, I only found [this information](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/node-shapes/) about changing the `block` shape. But as a gain is common block diagram component, there should be a fast and easy way.

Comment: You can use `isosceles triagle` or `regular polygon` shapes.

Comment: `block` is not a standard shape. How is it defined? You can use the `shapes.geometric` library for the shapes Zarko mentioned. Please provide a minimal working example.

Comment: @Zarko and cfr - I was unaware of the fact that I can define the shapes myself in the preamble. My solution was to use
`\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning}
 \tikzset{block/.style = {draw, fill=blue!20, rectangle,
                         minimum height=3em, minimum width=6em},
        mytriangle/.style = {draw, fill=blue!20, isosceles triangle, node distance=1cm},
 }` Both comments helped me equally. As you were the first contributer, I invite you to reformulate your comment as an answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An example how to define triangle shape (with use of `regular polygon`):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
amp/.style = {regular polygon, regular polygon sides=3,
              draw, fill=white, text width=1em,
              inner sep=1mm, outer sep=0mm,
              shape border rotate=-90}
                        ]
\node (amp) [amp,right] {A} -- ++ (2,0);
\draw (amp.west) -- ++ (-2,0)   (amp.east) -- ++ (2,0);       
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]